# I have two lists of map<String,Object>.I want to add first list element output into beginning of another list first element n so on

Tags: d3.js

```
for(String circle:a4)
            {
            Map<String,Object> mapgraphCircle=new HashMap<String,Object>(); 
            mapgraphCircle.put("id",circle.toLowerCase());
            mapgraphCircle.put("label",circle); 
            listgraphCircle.add(mapgraphCircle);
            System.out.println("listgraphCircle is "+listgraphCircle);  
          }

           for(Integer ols:al)
            {   
            Map<String,Object> mapgraphCircle=new HashMap<String,Object>(); 
            System.out.println("ols is "+ols);  
            mapgraphCircle.put("level",ols);
            listgraphCircle1.add(mapgraphCircle);
            System.out.println("listgraphCircle1 is "+listgraphCircle1);
            }   

        jsonCartList = gson1.toJson(listgraphCircle1);
        JSONArray jsonArrayCircle = new JSONArray(jsonCartList);
        System.out.println("jsonArrayCircle is: " + jsonArrayCircle);
        session.setAttribute("JSONnewCircle", jsonArrayCircle);
```

first list output is listgraphCircle is [{id=bacillus, label=Bacillus}, {id=candida, label=Candida}, {id=dorhea, label=Dorhea}, {id=pichia, label=Pichia}, {id=porphyromonas, label=Porphyromonas}]

another list output is
[{level=2}, {level=1}, {level=2}, {level=1}]

I want output as follow : [{level=2,id=bacillus, label=Bacillus},{level=1,id=candida, label=Candida},{level=2,id=dorhea, label=Dorhea},...]  How to get such a output?

Comment: Your comment belongs to the question body. Also please clean up the formatting, it's very hard to read the code.

Comment: Thanks! I have formatted the code.Can you give suggestions for required output?